# Concatenate twig path in javascript string

Tags: javascript, php, twig, slim-3

I'm working on a PHP site with Slim and Twig-View. Within this site I'm working on live search with Ajax. The idea is for the user to search for a string and for search results to appear as the user types. Everything is working fine so far. I'm able to get the results and render them with the appropriate image and text. The problem comes when creating the link for each result. With Slim Twig-view, when you create a link, you use the path_for() function:

```
{{ path_for('episode', { 'show_slug': path, 'episode_slug': episode }) }}';
```

In this case, the values for path and episode are being generated by Javascript. The problem is that if I try the following:

```
var path = '{{ path_for('episode', { 'show_slug': results[i].showPath, 'episode_slug': results[i].url }) }}';
```

I have also tried using double quotes:

```
var path = "{{ path_for('episode', { 'show_slug': results[i].showPath, 'episode_slug': results[i].url }) }}";
```

The resulting link is myurl/shows// instead of myurl/shows/show-slug/episode-slug

So, path_for() is actually working, but it's not reading the values for results[i].showPath and results[i].url. It looks like this is just a concatenation issue, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: The `var path =` statement would generate an error. Your inner quotes are interfering with the string literal

Comment: I have tried using both single quotes and double quotes, the problem still remains.

Comment: Try with a template string, with `${ }` to use the real variable values: ``var path = `{{ path_for('episode', { show_slug: ${results[i].showPath}, episode_slug: ${results[i].url} }) }}`;``

Comment: Either use the FOS Js routing bundle or use ajax. You can't use  javascripts variables in twig, as twig is rendered server side. More information [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/generate_url_javascript.html)